# What File Is the Local Save Saved To?

Tags: pc, final-fantasy-7

I bought the game on Steam and the cloud service has become unnerving, always being down. Where does the local save of the game save to?

Comment: I can't tell for FF7, but usually it's a more or less meaningful subdirectory `%appdata%` or `My Documents\My Games`. In rare cases savegames are also in the games folder itself, i.e. `Steamdir\steamapps\common\gamename`. Either way, a defunct cloud service should have no influence on your local savegames unless you play on multiple machines

Answer (score 3):

Your local saves are stored in `My Documents\Square Enix\FINAL FANTASY VII Steam\User_X\`

In the launcher you have the option to disable cloud saves, then it will save and load to and from disk.

Comment: Good luck playing the game, it's definitely one of the best in the series!